# Need a SQL to Laravel Eloquent Translation

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I need to translate the following SQL query into Laravel's Eloquent syntax:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM applications a
LEFT JOIN ratings r 
  ON a.id = r.application_id
 AND r.admin_id = 1
WHERE r.admin_id IS NULL
```

The only way I've been able to get it to work is running the query using DB::raw, but I'm curious how it should look when using the Eloquent syntax. Ideally, I'd like to be able to migrate to any other database without a hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a closure to a join. You need to use `DB::raw()` as you're specifying a variable, rather than another database column to join on.

```
DB::table('applications')
    ->select('applications.*')
    ->leftJoin('ratings', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('ratings.application_id', '=', 'applications.id');
        $join->on('ratings.admin_id', '=', DB::raw('1'));
    })
    ->whereNull('ratings.admin_id')
    ->get()
```